# Will iOS frameworks be included in my build if I don't use them at all?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Asking this question mostly in relation to the big [Facebook SDK crash](https://9to5mac.com/2020/07/10/app-crash-facebook-sdk/) that frustrated many iOS developers last year.

Let's say I included the FB SDK in my app via CocoaPods, run `pod install` to initialize that framework and link it to my app, but then never reference any of that framework's code. When I go to package my app for distribution, will the build process actually include that CocoaPods dependency in my package?

I'm considering usage of pre-processor flags to essentially "ignore" import statements of certain 3rd party SDKs within a project I develop. Since those preprocessor flags essentially would cause the compiler to ignore referencing any of the 3rd party dependencies, I know that we can rely on that 3rd party SDK's code never being executed, but I'm wondering if because I'm also ignoring "import" or "include" statements, will the Xcode build process even build that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They will be included. A quick test by building your app this way and looking at the output will show you what happens.